# Minimize multivariate function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have the following simple example of a function of several variables

```
@tf.function
def f(A, Y, X):
  AX = tf.matmul(A, X)
  norm = tf.norm(Y - AX)
  return norm

N = 2
A = tf.Variable(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
Y = tf.Variable(np.identity(N))
X = tf.Variable(np.zeros((N, N)))
```

How do I find `X` that minimizes `f` with Tensorflow ?
I would be interested in a generic solution that works with a function declared as above and when there are more than one variable to optimize.

Comment: Using an [optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer)...? But you are using NumPy functions (`np.`) within a [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/function) (I suppose you are using TF 2.x?), so that is not going to work. (Also I suppose by `tf.variables` you meant `tf.Variable`?)

Comment: @jdehesa I removed numpy from `f` and corrected "variables".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Tensorflow 2, you can use a Keras optimizer:

```
@tf.function
def f(A, Y, X):
    AX = tf.matmul(A, X)
    norm = tf.norm(Y - AX)
    return norm

N = 2
A = tf.Variable(np.array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]]))
Y = tf.Variable(np.identity(N))
X = tf.Variable(np.zeros((N, N)))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()
for iteration in range(0, 100):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = f(X, Y, X)
        print(loss)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, [A, Y, X])
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, [A, Y, X]))

print(A, Y, X)
```

That will work for any differentiable function. For non-differentiable functions you could look at other optimization techniques (such as Genetic Algorithms, or Swarm Optimization. NEAT has implementations of these https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: This answer works if A and Y are variables, but the question was to find X. A and Y should be constants

Answer (score 5):

[avanwyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57760061/1782792) is essentially right, although note that: 1) you can directly use the [`minimize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#minimize) method of the optimizer for simplicity 2) if you only want to optimize `X` you should make sure that is the only variable you are updating.

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def f(A, Y, X):
  AX = tf.matmul(A, X)
  norm = tf.norm(Y - AX)
  return norm

# Input data
N = 2
A = tf.Variable([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]], tf.float32)
Y = tf.Variable(tf.eye(N, dtype=tf.float32))
X = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((N, N), tf.float32))
# Initial function value
print(f(A, Y, X).numpy())
# 1.4142135

# Setup a stochastic gradient descent optimizer
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)
# Define loss function and variables to optimize
loss_fn = lambda: f(A, Y, X)
var_list = [X]
# Optimize for a fixed number of steps
for _ in range(1000):
    opt.minimize(loss_fn, var_list)

# Optimized function value
print(f(A, Y, X).numpy())
# 0.14933111

# Optimized variable
print(X.numpy())
# [[-2.0012102   0.98504114]
#  [ 1.4754106  -0.5111093 ]]
```

Comment: Hi, i have a large data set of inputs and outputs ( 100 input parameters and 100 output value). Is it possible to use tensorflow to do extrapolation/interpolation over such data set? I tried genetic algorithm to minimize this set, however with so many input parameters this does not work so well.